# Migrating Springdoc from Springfox

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, springfox, springdoc

I am working on a legacy project (still uses Spring Boot 1.5).
Our team tasked with upgrading the project and one of the task is update Springfox to Springdoc.

I have change all annotations and I think it works because I can get the YAML or JSON file using `/v3/api-docs` URL.

One think that I cannot access is the Swagger UI. In the `application.yml`, I have added this:

```yaml
springdoc:
  api-docs:
    resolve-schema-properties: true
  swagger-ui:
    use-root-path: true
    validatorUrl: none
    path: /swagger-ui
    operationsSorter: alpha
    tagsSorter: alpha
    docExpansion: none
```

But everytime I access `/swagger-ui/index.html` or `/swagger-ui.html`, it seems it got error due to security or filter chain. There is security dependency in the project. I am newbie here so any suggestion what I can check. How to debug this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow unauthenticated access to the Swagger resources in your Spring Security config. The following worked for me:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class WebSecurityConfiguration {

    private static final String[] SWAGGER_PATHS = {"/swagger-ui.html", "/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui/**", "/webjars/swagger-ui/**"};

    private final UserRegistrationFilter authenticationTokenFilter;

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain filterChain(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
            // Configure access rules
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                .antMatchers(SWAGGER_PATHS).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated())

            // All your other config

            .build();
    }

}
```